# DjangoCMS plugin OperationalError at /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/ - no such table: cmsplugin_soundcloud_soundcloud

Tags: python, plugins, soundcloud, django-cms

I am using djangoCMS. I am trying to get the [SoundCloud plugin](https://github.com/misli/cmsplugin-soundcloud) to work. After a few fixes that I could handle I came across this error:

```
    OperationalError at /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/ 
no such table: cmsplugin_soundcloud_soundcloud
```

which I can't get my head around. This appears in edit mode on DjangoCMS' frontend at the moment of saving the instance a the plugin.

Here are the fixes I did:

In /Lib/site-packages/cmsplugin_soundcloud/models.py
change `from urllib import urlencode` to `from urllib.parse import urlencode`
change `from urllib2 import urlopen` to `from urllib.request import urlopen`
change `from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, parse_qsl` to `from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, parse_qsl`

In /Lib/site-packages/cmsplugin_soundcloud/cmsplugins.py
add  `render_template = "cmsplugin_soundcloud.html "`

I am not sure issue is triggered by the fixes I did and if a quick fix can be applied.

Bellow is the traceback.
Thanks.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/?placeholder_id=21&plugin_type=SoundCloudPlugin&cms_path=/en/music/?structure&plugin_language=en

Django Version: 3.1.8
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['djangocms_admin_style',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'cms',
 'menus',
 'sekizai',
 'treebeard',
 'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
 'filer',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_alerts',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_badge',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_card',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_carousel',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_collapse',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_content',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_grid',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_jumbotron',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_link',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_listgroup',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_media',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_picture',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_tabs',
 'djangocms_bootstrap4.contrib.bootstrap4_utilities',
 'djangocms_file',
 'djangocms_icon',
 'djangocms_link',
 'djangocms_picture',
 'djangocms_style',
 'djangocms_googlemap',
 'djangocms_video',
 'tinymce',
 'djangocms_vimeo',
 'cmsplugin_soundcloud',
 'mySite']
Installed Middleware:
['cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: cmsplugin_soundcloud_soundcloud) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\clickjacking.py", line 33, in wrapped_view
    resp = view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\cms\admin\placeholderadmin.py", line 341, in add_plugin
    response = plugin_instance.add_view(request)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1580, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\cmsplugin_soundcloud\cms_plugins.py", line 27, in save_model
    return super(SoundCloudPlugin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\cms\plugin_base.py", line 335, in save_model
    return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1093, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\cms\models\pluginmodel.py", line 265, in save
    self.add_root(instance=self)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\treebeard\mp_tree.py", line 617, in add_root
    return MP_AddRootHandler(cls, **kwargs).process()
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\treebeard\mp_tree.py", line 335, in process
    newobj.save()
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\cms\models\pluginmodel.py", line 267, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/
Exception Value: no such table: cmsplugin_soundcloud_soundcloud
```

Comment: Seems the tables for the soundcloud plugin are missing. Have you tried to make all migrations and run migrate (`./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`)?

Comment: Hi @Fabian, thanks for your suggestion but yes I did... I have tried again but it expectedly didn't change anything in the traceback.

Comment: Then I assume Django thinks it has already created these tables despite the fact that the table is missing. If and only if you do not have any existing soundcloud plugins you could try to delete all tables starting with ``cmsplugin_soundcloud``. Then remove soundcloud from Django's migration memory: Delete all entries in ``django_migrations`` with ``app="cmsplugin_soundcloud"``. Finally run the management command ``migrate``.

Comment: @Fabian, maybe I should have mentioned (or maybe you guessed it), I get the error on the frontend when I want to save the Soundcloud plugin (until the saving it seems working all fine). Since I get the error I can't save it and I have to delete it so technically I don't have any existing Soundcloud plugins. 
Could you elaborate a bit more on where the tables I should delete are located? and also what file contains the Django's migration memory ? I am far from being a master at DjangoCMS... 
Also is it normal that there is no migrations folder in /Lib/site-packages/cmsplugin_soundcloud ? Thx!

Comment: Django's migration memory is the table `django_migrations` in you database.  You can access it using Django by running `./manage.py shell`, then `from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder` and then see all soundcloud migrations using `MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app="cmsplugin_soundcloud")`. I assume they are marked as executed despite the fact that they are not or failed. Delete them using `MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app="cmsplugin_soundcloud").delete()` and try `migrate` again.

Comment: If soundloud's migrations only ran partially, the `migrate` command might complain that some soundcloud tables already exist. They would have to be removed by hand from your database. What database are you using?

Comment: Thx @Fabian, when I proceed as you described, I get `<QuerySet []>` as an answer. When I change `(app="cmsplugin_soundcloud")` with another app, which works, I get a list of all the migrations, which are in the Lib/site-packages/app/migrations folder of that app. (There is no mentioning of whether the migrations are executed properly or not.) For Soundcloud, there is no folder migrations altogether... So maybe those tables are indeed missing. What can I do then?
Sorry I don't know how to answer the question what database I use. I never chose any, so I guess it's the standard one?

Comment: OK, any migration listed in the QuerySet supposedly finished properly. Now, the question remains, why the soundcloud migrations are not applied. In case the soundcloud migrations are missing can you try `./manage.py makemigrations cmsplugin_soundcloud` and the `./manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @Fabian, yes that worked! Thanks a lot. I am puzzled why the migrations didn't happen when I ran the command (./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate) ... weird.
There is now an issue within the plugin: if it points to a Soudcloud track without any description then an error is raised `Exception Type: IntegrityError at /en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: cmsplugin_soundcloud_soundcloud.description
` but I guess I'll make sure to have descriptions until I find a nicer fix.

Comment: Well there might very well be something fishy with that app or I am completely missing out on something: Now when I edit the models.py and I run`manage.py makemigrations cmsplugin_soundcloud` I get `No changes detected in app 'cmsplugin_soundcloud`. I have successfully (maybe not the most elegant way) fixed the `cmsplugin_soundcloud_soundcloud.description` error I mentioned before and I enabled the setting of web colours. But now for a last editing about the `self.title = properties['title']`, whatever I do is NOTrendered to the template cmsplugin_soundcloud.html... weird.

Comment: I have no knowledge of the plugin whatsoever. Django treats empty values for CharFields as empty strings not as null. Maybe you did not edit the installed copy of the plugin? At least that was a problem I had once. :-)

Comment: Hehe, no: first the new editing sits in the same method (`load_data()` in model.py) right after the previous editing I did and which was taken into account. I also doublechecked with other irrelevant edits in the `SoundCloud(CMSPlugin)` class but outside the methods, and _these_ where taken into account ...